# configuring log with Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, io

I have developed a spring application, I want to configure it with apache log4j, have downloaded it and put the jar in project's class path. Below is my log4j.Properties file.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C\:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And below is my main spring application class.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingClass {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //without dependency injection 
        /*Triangle t1 = new Triangle();
        t1.draw();*/


        //with dependency injection     
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Spring.xml"));
        Triangle t1 =(Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
        t1.draw();
    }
}
```

Please advise if I want to put the log.info in my above main class what modifications I need to do in my main class and also please advise what modifications I need to done to call log4j in my main class?

come up with this solution and it works ..the edited log4j.properties file is

```
### direct messages to file or.log ###
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/logs/s.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.append=true

### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ##
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, file
log4j.logger.Demo=\=debug
log4j.logger.org.eclipse=debug
```

and the way to callit from main class is

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingClass {
     /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DrawingClass.class);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        //without dependency injection 
        /*Triangle t1 = new Triangle();
        t1.draw();*/

         log.info("Before execution");
        //with dependency injection     
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Spring.xml"));
        Triangle t1 =(Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
        log.info("Hello this is an info message");
        t1.draw();
         log.info("after object execution");
    }
}
```

If there is any other better way then please advise .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding this line to your class -

```
public class DrawingClass {

   static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DrawingClass.class);

public static void main(String args[])
{
    //without dependency injection 
    /*Triangle t1 = new Triangle();
    t1.draw();*/

    log.info("Before execution");
    //with dependency injection     
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Spring.xml"));
    Triangle t1 =(Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
    t1.draw();
}
 }
```

Now let me know if anything gets added to the log.

This link might help you - http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/sample-log4j-properties-file-configuration-1.html

Comment: ..getting this warning message on console..log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Demo.DrawingClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: You will have to add another statement to your properties file. Just give me some time I'll let you know.

Comment: You are getting this error because your log4j configuration file(i.e. log4j.xml or log4j.properties) is NOT found in the classpath. Placing the log4j configuration file in the applications classpath should solve the issue.

Comment: Nice you found the answer. I had never used a log4j.properties file. I always use the log4j.xml so was not able to give you the complete answer.

Comment: thanks a lot , could you please also update the log4j.xml so that I can also learn it , would be great if you can post here as I have done with regard to my program, That would be a great help,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For using logging in my project I made such things:

1) Defined special annotation that should mark fields where logger should be injected:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)  
@Target(FIELD)  
@Documented  
public @interface InjectLogger {  
}
```

2) Then created special BeanPostProcessor for injected logger into annotated field:

```
@Component(value="loggerInjector")
public class LoggerInjector implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new FieldCallback() {  
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException,  
            IllegalAccessException {  
                // make the field accessible if defined private  
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);  
                if (field.getAnnotation(InjectLogger.class) != null) {  
                    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(bean.getClass()); 
                    field.set(bean, log);  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        return bean;  
    }  

}
```

3) After this in necessary bean mark property where logger should be injected by @InjectLogger annotation and use this logger in your code.

```
    @InjectLogger
    private Logger logger;

public void doSomething(...) {
     try{
     ...
     } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("bla bla bla", e);
     }
}
```

In my project I use slf4j with log4j as concrete implementation. But with log4j it will be similar.

Also you need to know that by default all Spring libs using common-logging. And if you want that Spring libs write their log to your file you should use special additionla lib. You can get them, as I remember, from appache site. For slf4j such lib is named jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar.

EDIT 2:

Also in spring the good practise is to use AOP for logging. Here is an example of simplified Aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(value=2)
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.blablabla.server..*.*(..))")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        Object retVal = null;

        try {
            StringBuffer startMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            startMessageStringBuffer.append("Start method ");
            startMessageStringBuffer.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            startMessageStringBuffer.append("(");

            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                startMessageStringBuffer.append(args[i]).append(",");
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                startMessageStringBuffer.deleteCharAt(startMessageStringBuffer.length() - 1);
            }

            startMessageStringBuffer.append(")");

            logger.trace(startMessageStringBuffer.toString());

            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();

            retVal = joinPoint.proceed();

            stopWatch.stop();

            StringBuffer endMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            endMessageStringBuffer.append("Finish method ");
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            endMessageStringBuffer.append("(..); execution time: ");
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(" ms;");

            logger.trace(endMessageStringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            StringBuffer errorMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

             // Create error message 
             logger.error(errorMessageStringBuffer.toString(), e)

            throw ex;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But this really not very hard approach and it is easy to use. I use logging based on AOP approach and where necessary inject logger into bean and log some message manually.

Answer (score 0):

```css
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger= DEBUG, INFO, Appender1, Appender2
 
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
 
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=D:/Project Log/Demo/demo.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Write this code in log4j.properties which is in Resources folder of src folder.

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Write this above code in porm.xml file or download jar for this dependency.

```html
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:log4j.properties" />
```

write this above code between  and  in your spring-config.xml

```js
package com.apmc.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import com.apmc.Generic.RandomGenerator;//This my own made class So You need to create //RandomGenerator for use it


@Controller
public class StateController {
 
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StateController.class);
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss");
 Date dateobj = new Date();
    int randNum = RandomGenerator.randInt(1000, 9999);
    String successMsg = "", errorMsg = "";

    @Autowired
 StateService stateService;
 
 List<State> newList = new ArrayList();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Admin/admin/NewState_form")
 public ModelAndView stateForm(@ModelAttribute State state) {
     
    try {
   logger.info("\n stateForm Started \n errorcode : "+errorcode);
   newList = stateService.loadAll();
   logger.info("\n stateForm Completed");
   errorMsg = "";
 }  catch (Exception e) {
   errorcode = ""+df.format(dateobj)+randNum;
   errorMsg = " New State Form Error \n Please contact Admin and errorcode:"                           +errorcode;
   successMsg = "";
   logger.error("error code for stateForm in StateController"                                            +df.format(dateobj)+" errorcode: "+errorcode);
 }
  
    return new ModelAndView("state").addObject("editState",                                                                             new State())
                                    .addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg)                                                         .addObject("showStateList",newList)
                                    .addObject("successMsg", successMsg);
    }
}
```

Above example for how to use log in Controller or any Java Class
Here I made for error Tracking create error code show for commmunicate with error using RandomGenerator.java write as below given

```js
package com.apmc.Generic;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGenerator {
 
 /**
  * Returns a pseudo-random number between min and max, inclusive.
  * The difference between min and max can be at most
  * <code>Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1</code>.
  *
  * @param min Minimum value
  * @param max Maximum value.  Must be greater than min.
  * @return Integer between min and max, inclusive.
  * @see java.util.Random#nextInt(int)
  */
 public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

     // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
     // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
     Random rand = new Random();

     // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
     // so add 1 to make it inclusive
     int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

     return randomNum;
 }
}
```